# Python adding dict to pandas DataFrame as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My DataFrame looks something like this:

```
A,  B
1,  f
```

I've got a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{'M':[1,2,3]}
```

What i'd like to do is to add the dict into the Dataframe as a column:

```
A,  B,  C
1,  f,  {'M':[1,2,3]}
```

It's not important for the C column to be a dict i just need a key value pair where the value is an array.

Could someone explain to men how i could do this?

Comment: `df.loc[0, 'C'] = {'M' : [1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Working nice

Comment: @jezrael thanks man... was wondering whether it was a dupe, but could not find one so am posting an answer ...

Comment: Why, but *why*, would you do this??

Comment: @colspeed thanks but i had the problem that i had multiple keys and then an error occured the solution was to put the dict into an array and then it worked. At least i do understand it better now Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `assign`

```
df.assign(C=[{'M': [1, 2, 3]}])

   A  B                 C
0  1  f  {'M': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you very much.
My fault was to add the dict directly so i had a value error. 
The dict must be inside of an array.

Comment: @swas if you were trying to add more than one dict, you should have indicated as such in your question

Answer (score 3):

Assign with `loc`:

```
df.loc[0, 'C'] = {'M' : [1, 2, 3]}
```

```
df
   A  B                 C
0  1  f  {'M': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding []

```
df['C']=[{'M':[1,2,3]}]
df
Out[11]: 
   A    B                 C
0  1    f  {'M': [1, 2, 3]}
```